# Cant install pyscipopt in windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyscipopt

I am trying to do linear programming in python and want to use the PyScipOPT library.

I have done these steps:

1. Download the SCIPOptSuite
2. Updated my path environments
3. set SCIPOPTDIR correctly
4. ran pip install pyscipopt

Terminal output

```
  × Building wheel for pyscipopt (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Using include path C:\Program Files\SCIPOptSuite 8.0.3\include.
      Using SCIP library libscip at C:\Program Files\SCIPOptSuite 8.0.3\lib.

      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\cutsel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\reader.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\pyscipopt
      running build_ext
      building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyscipopt
Failed to build pyscipopt
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyscipopt, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: It is heavily recommended that you install PySCIPOpt using anaconda, especially on Windows.

Comment: Me too, same error.